# Calculate a polynomial. Without knowing its formula.

Tags: polynomials

The degree of the polynomial $W(x)$ is $2015$   
$W(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ for  $ n \in \{1,2,3,...,2016\}$

Calculate $W(2017)$.

---

I came to the conclusion $f(x) = 1 - xW(x)$, after checking all the $n$ and the degrees of the polynomials. $f(x) = a(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)...(x-2016)$ so $W(x) = \frac{1-f(x)}{x}$
After seeing an similar question I know that $a = \frac{1}{2016!}$ but how to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove this, note that the constant term of
$$f(x)=1-xW(x)$$
is $1$, so that $f(0)=1$, and therefore $1/a=(-1)^{2016}2016!$.

Answer (score 0):

You need $1-f(0)$ to be $0$, because otherwise $\frac{1-f(x)}{x}$ would blow up at $0$ and then it certainly wouldn't be a polynomial function.

So $f(0) = a\cdot 2016!$ must be $1$.